# Is it safe to put a clothes washer outdoors?

Tags: appliances, outdoor

I will be short on usable indoor space for a while, but want to be able to wash clothes on site.

Are there any issues with putting a washer (and perhaps, a dryer) outdoors?

Perhaps it needs to be protected from the rain. Would an EZ-UP style canopy be sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't protect these appliances and the power feeds from rain don't expect them to work for long. If excessive moisture gets into the control panel, especially on newer electronic controlled units, they will fail.

Would you leave your computer outdoors?  Also remember the dryer is a 240VAC, 30amp unit and can light up your world if the the frame becomes hot, since I'm sure you don't plan on having GFIC protection on these units.

If you really have to use these outside, keep them covered well and unplugged when not in use, and keep the source power cords safe too.

Comment: You probably need to get them off of the ground as well.  A wooden pallet or platform should work.

Comment: Yes, you super super super want in a big way to use a proper separately grounded 4-prong dryer connection, not the obsolete NEMA 10 3-prong setups.  Perhaps with a separate ground strap also, belt *and* suspenders (as opposed to "no pants" which would be NEMA 10).  GFCI is nice, but letting the metal chassis of the machine do its job is better.

Answer (score 8):

As long as you protect it and all the electrical cords from the elements, I don't see problem with a washer being outdoors.  Where do you plan to drain the soapy water?  It's a lot of water and would make a huge mess if it isn't attached to a proper drain.

Comment: "Laundry to Landscape" - http://www.oasisdesign.net/greywater/laundry/

Answer (score 7):

I have a friend who has a washer and dryer on his screened-in porch. He's mentioned that he's had his clothes frozen solid in the washer before, and the pipes have frozen on him as well. If you live in a cold climate, that could be a major factor.

Comment: Good point... I didn't think about freezing temps.

Comment: We don't get much freezing around here, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: That'll put starch in your shorts.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to check the warranty details too.  Some manufacturers have strict requirements on the operating conditions of their equipment.

Comment: I was thinking I get an old unit off Craigslist, since it will probably age faster outdoors.

Answer (score 1):

I also keep my washer and dryer out doors under a canapy! So I buy them used not repaired on the discount floor at any Lows ‘s etc at half the cost . Most of them are returns because they been scratched ! Who cares when their out side . I live in southern countrie near the beach. The weather is awesome for out door Laundry.

Answer (score 1):

I have a digital washer and dryer outside under a overhang for 12 years now and it has yet to give me any problems, when u are not using it just throw a sheet and canvas over over it and that will take care of any kind of moisture coming from the air, you just cant keep it exposed to the elements when not in use but really not that big of a deal if u just throw a sheet and canvas over it

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It really depends on your location, although the OP didn't say.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a washer and dryer that is listed for use outdoors. They cannot be installed in patios, sheds, or any other type of outdoor enclosure unless listed for outdoor use.